# How to select multiple items using mouse click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

This is the default jQueryUI display as a Grid Layouts ([demo here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#display-grid)). I can select one at a time when using mouse pointer. I have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for multiple selections. How will I edit the code for multiple selections at once using just the mouse pointer?

#### CSS

```
<style>
    #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
    #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
    #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
    #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 80px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
</style>
```

#### JavaScript

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
    });
</script>
```

#### HTML

```
 <div class="demo"> 
   <ol id="selectable">
     <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
   </ol>
 </div><!-- End demo -->
 
 <div class="demo-description">
   <p>To arrange selectable items as a grid, give them identical dimensions and float them using CSS.</p>
 </div><!-- End demo-description -->
```

Comment: Show up the jQueryui's sources for `.selectable();`

Comment: I don't understand what are you talking about ? can you give me the code using http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Since you know about jsFiddle, it would be a good idea if you put the code there for everyone ;-)

Comment: "How will I edit the code for multiple selections at once using just the mouse pointer?" <-- What does that mean? What are you trying to do? Style the selected items different? Do something with the selected items?

Comment: Anybody know how to do this ? i think it isn't big code

Comment: did you see the DEMO.we can not select multiple boxes at one ? if you want to select we want to use press CTRL and the muse pointer.But i want to know how to do that along with mouse pointer ? any ideas ?

Comment: I meant that the framework method `.selectable();`is doing all the stuff, so, if there's no configs to `.selectable()` its source code is needed to remade the functionality. Sorry for my English.

Comment: And something, that you probably may need http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox

Comment: Thank in advanced for given this URL http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox........

Comment: Should i post it like an answer? ^_^

Comment: yeah.but  that is another method.i think we have to edit Jquery UI core for use such a functions

Comment: Maybe you can do it by providing a `selecting` event handler to `.selectable()`? See http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#event-selecting

Comment: You want a draggable selection? Likes we select multiple icons?

Comment: No.we can not select  multiple items at ones using mouse pointer .we want to use CTRL for that .How to do this ? I wrote many times this words but anyone can not understand my problem ? O_o

Comment: You wanna simulate `ctrl+mouse_left_button` just with `mouse_left_button`, right?

Comment: @Samitha, there's one important thing here: to accept the answer in case it has answered your question. The "tick" below the downvote button near every answer will do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found This Code Online. Is that what you are asking for?

[Multiple Select With Ctrl](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfevM/99/)

Comment: And what is the big difference with http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#display-grid ?

Comment: You've got +20, that is definitely bigger +15 ;)

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left click for selecting multiple items is pretty standard UI behaviour and built-in to the [jQueryUI Selectable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/). Did you also know you can left click and drag a focus over multiple items to select them?

However, I can see an advantage in offering the behaviour in question, so how about using left click or drag to select and then left click and drag to also *de-select*?

It may not be the most efficient way of doing it, but after playing around with the in-built callbacks, I've come up with something that seems to work. Based on the code in your question I've hooked into the in-built callback functions to store what was selected and also handle the selection removal. JavaScript duplicated below but [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ALmkj/1/).

#### JavaScript

```
var $currentlySelected = null;
var selected = [];

$('#selectable').selectable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        $currentlySelected = $('#selectable .ui-selected');
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
            if ($.inArray(selected[i], $currentlySelected) >= 0) {
              $(selected[i]).removeClass('ui-selected');
            }
        }
        selected = [];
    },
    selecting: function(event, ui) {
        $currentlySelected.addClass('ui-selected'); // re-apply ui-selected class to currently selected items
    },
    selected: function(event, ui) {
        selected.push(ui.selected); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox
Looks like the thing you are looking for

Comment: yeah.I want to use this select functions for my given demo .How to do that ?

Comment: Actually that's not as easy as it may seem to you. JQueryUI lib method should be remade.

Comment: @Samitha, stolen from Kakarott and changed to newer version of jquery =) http://jsfiddle.net/ZfevM/100/

Comment: Let me guess what is changed..NOTHING !!

Comment: @kakarott, actually there is some change that made it work for me. Don't be angry, all credits, as the correct answer should be yours ;)

Comment: @ted thanks dear.i'll apply it for my given demo.thanks many times again .However great efforts from the ted

Comment: aaaanndd here goes my +15 :\ :\

Comment: @kakarott does not understand my problem but he helped for ted answer :p

Comment: I've just changed the jquery lib to newer version for his solution to work(for me at least), nothing more.

Comment: ted's answer :O
I answer before him but deleted, thought you dont want this. :\
But..well..no problem. Hakuna Matata :P